# Find the equation of the line that passes through the point $(2, 1, 0)$ and is perpendicular to the plane $4x - 3y + 5z + 3 = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the equation of the line that passes through the point $(2, 1, 0)$ and is perpendicular to the plane $4x - 3y + 5z + 3 = 0$

Comment: "Find the equation of the line": what type of line equation do you expect ?

Comment: If you really mean _equation_, I think you need two of them to determine a line.

Answer (score 1):

First note that plane $4x-3y+5z=0$ is parallel to $4x-3y+5z+3=0$. Now the normal vector to $4x-3x+5z=0$ is $(4,-3,5)$, finally line $\{(4,-3,5)t+(2,1,0) : t \in \mathbb{R} \}$ passes throw the point $(2,1,0)$ (if you put $t=0$ you see that).

Comment: How would you find the equation of the perpindicular line that passes through that point?

Comment: Put $t=0$, then you get $(2,1,0)$.

Comment: Notice that this gives the parametric equations $x=2+4t, y=1-3t, z=5t$ for the line.